# Loading Json data to DropdownList

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have to load data to ddl from json file in my application, for ex

I have countries.json in my application,

same as state, and city,

```
[{"label":"US Dollars (USD)","country":"US","value": "USD"},"label":"CA Dollars (CAD)","country":"CA","value": "CAD"},{"label":"UK Pounds (GBP)","country":"UK","value": "GBP"}]
```

I am doing this for decreasing the roundtrip, and loading data directly from json file.

Can anyone please suggest me how I can do this in mvc application.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote a blog post that populates a dropdown from json using an api endpoint but the populating part is still the same

http://jnye.co/Posts/12/creating-cascading-dropdownlists-using-mvc-4-and-jquery

You want to go through each item and add an `<option>` to you drop down

```
                var dropdown = $('#ddl');
                //clear drop down of old states
                stateDropdown.empty();

                //retrieve data for ddl...
                var data = ...

                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    //Create new option
                    var option = $('<option />').html(item.label);
                    //append state states drop down
                    dropdown .append(option);
                });
```

NOTE: I'm not at an IDE so forgive any speeling/naming mistakes

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do this well enough, although if you are binding a lot of JavaScript objects to your UI you might want to look at a framework like Knockout.js

```
var ddl = $('<select></select>');

for(var i = 0; i < yourJsonObj.length; i++) {
    var currency = yourJsonObj[i];
    ddl.append($('<option></option>').val(currency.value).text(currency.label));
}

$('body').append(ddl);
```

EDIT:
I noticed you specified MVC tag rather than JavaScript. JavaScript can natively understand JSON so it is easiest to do this on the client. If you are wanting to do this in a C# Model or Controller, you will probably want to use a library like json.NET to easily parse the JSON into your desired type.